# Paypal PHP SDK Not found! Fatal error: Class 'string' not found

Tags: php, sdk, paypal

I need to execute the  `phpsdk` `paypal` samples  on:

http://www.fastbreakplay.com/preview/paypal/sample/

but I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'string' not found in
>   /home/fastbre/public_html/preview/paypal/sample/vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Common/Model.php
>   on line 53

Comment: You need to post some source code before anyone can help you out. Specifically, line 53 of the file you referenced.

Comment: $o = new $clazz(); //this is the line 53

Comment: the completed file is:
https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/blob/master/lib/PayPal/Common/Model.php

Answer (score 0):

The product you are using is  rest-api-sdk-php

https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php

If you look under issues, two days ago there
was an issue reported that may be related to 
your problem.

https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/issues/4

As you can see in the issue, they had some 
 issues updating. That could have messed up
 all kinds of things. They were suggesting
 removing the vendor folder and
 composer.lock files; then doing a composer update.

Since your problem was in the vendor directory, and
you may have been installing around the time of 
this update issue, you may want to try their
suggestion.